# how to convert a dict input to long text in python

Tags: python, flask

Hey everyone I have a dictionary in my input and I want to convert it to a long text for translation goal,

can anyone show me please how to convert dict to text in python3

```
@app.route('/translate_text', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def translate_text(target='fr'):

    translate_client = translate.Client()
    text = request.form['texttotrans']
    result = translate_client.translate(text,target_language=target)
    app.logger.info(result)
    return "Check your console"
```

Comment: Please add some example, that will help us to answer your question better

Comment: okay i have added it above

Comment: You have added the code, not example. What I meant was - some example dict and example output you expect once it is converted into text

Comment: i have also another request  , like this example , list = ["text1","text2","text3","text4"]

result :

text1 text2 text3 text4 , it solved thankx ,

Comment: Here you added `list` as your input, but your question says `dict`?

Comment: yeah i solved it in json, now i want to convert from list to text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `json` package:

```py
import json
your_dict = {'a':1}
json.dumps(your_dict) # '{a:1}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use **str()** like

```
dictionary = { 'a':1, 'b':2}
str(dictionary)
# "{'a': 1, 'b': 2}"
```

or **json.dumps()** like

```
import json
dictionary = { 'a':1, 'b':2}
json.dumps(dictionary)
# '{"a": 1, "b": 2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dict_sample = {'key1':1,'val1':2}
x=str(dict_sample) 
print(x)
```

str() casts the dictionary to string.

This would be the simplest way without importing any packages so does not have any dependencies